# How to replace characters and rename multiple files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

I have a bunch of pdf files which has the file name as follows:

1. AuthorA_2014_ This is a good article
2. BIsanotherAuthor_1994_ Gr8 artcle
3. CIsFatherOfB_1994_Minor article but not bad

And so on. I would like to change the name of the files to this format:

1. AuthorA2014This is a good article
2. BIsanotherAuthor1994Gr8 artcle
3. CIsFatherOfB1994Minor article but not bad

How do I do this in python? I do have a beginner level knowledge in python. I tried with the code taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/igniteflow/1226919)

```
import os
path =  os.getcwd()
filenames = os.listdir(path)
for filename in filenames:
    os.rename(filename, filename.replace("_", ""))
```

With this code I could change the title from AuthorA_2014_ This is a good article to AuthorA2014 This is a good article, which deletes the underscores, but I do not want any empty spaces between the year and title of the article. How do I accomplish this?

I am using Python 3.7.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get it done:

```
import os
path =  os.getcwd()
filenames = os.listdir(path)
for filename in filenames:
    os.rename(filename, filename.replace("_", "").replace("_ ", ""))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex to remove an `_` with an optional trailing space:

```
import re
import os
path =  os.getcwd()
filenames = os.listdir(path)
for filename in filenames:
    os.rename(filename, re.sub(r'_ ?', '', filename))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
import os
path =  os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path)
for file in files:
    os.rename(file, re.sub(r'_ ?', '', file))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using [pathlib](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/):

- *This module offers classes representing filesystem paths with semantics appropriate for different operating systems.*
- Given a pathlib object created with `t = Path.cwd() / 'test_foo_ bar.txt'`

  - [`.rglob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob) to find all the `.pdf` files
  - `WindowsPath('E:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/test_foo_ bar.txt')`
  - [`t.stem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem) is `'test_foo_ bar'`
  - [`t.suffix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.suffix) is `'.txt'`
  - [`t.parent`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parent) is `WindowsPath('E:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow')`

    - `t.parent / 'new_name.txt'` is `WindowsPath('E:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/new_name.txt')`
  - [`t.rename(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rename) renames the file

```py
from pathlib import Path

p = Path.cwd()  # for current working directory or Path('/some_path/files')
for file in p.rglob('*.pdf'):  # get all pdfs in all subdirectories
    new_file_name = file.stem.replace('_', '').replace('_ ', '') + file.suffix
    file.rename(file.parent / new_file_name)
```