# Remove all print statements in a python program in one go

Tags: python, editor

Recently I went on to clean my python code. I felt tiresome to remove all print statements in the code ony by one.

Is there any shortcut in editor or RE for removing or commenting print statements in a python program in one go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Find / Replace

- Find Replace `print(` with `# print(` will comment them out
- Probably works in most editors

### Using [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/) with regex

- Free to download
- Recognizes many programming languages
- Search expression `(print).*`

  - `^(print).*` if you only want print statements from the beginning of the line
  - [image]

[image]

### Write a script

- Use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to find files

  - [How to replace characters and rename multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62668490)
  - [Python 3's pathlib Module: Taming the File System](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/)
- Use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to find and replace expression

```py
from pathlib import Path

p = Path('c:\...\path_to_python_files')  # path to directory with files
files = list(p.rglob('*.py'))  # find all python files including subdirectories of p

for file in files:
    with file.open('r') as f:
        rows = [re.sub('(print).*', '', row) for row in f.readlines()]
    
    new_file_name = file.parent / f'{file.stem}_no_print{file.suffix}'

    with new_file_name.open('w') as f:  # you could overwrite the original file, but that might be scary
        f.writelines(rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid working with print statements. Use the python logging module instead:

```
import logging
logging.debug('debug message')
```

Once you finished your development and dont need debugging information, you can increase the log level:

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s:%(message)s', level=logging.WARNING)
```

This suppresses all logging messages lower than WARNING.
See the [DOCS](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

1. Open Text Editor in Ubuntu
2. Press Ctrl + h
3. Replace: print
4. Replace with: # print